# Risk of apt-get upgrade on Ubuntu 12.04 with manually installed Cuda 6.5

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, upgrade, cuda

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 along with a manually installed Cuda 6.5. I'm wondering if there is a risk doing apt-get upgrade?
The question is: 
Does apt-get upgrade install some default Ubuntu Nvidia drivers which might mess up my system because they are conflicting with my manually installed Cuda 6.5?

Does anyone have experience with that?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/575161/344926) the automatic updates doesn't even know that the cuda 6.5 is installed nor any of its dependencies that were installed with it, so you are safe tu run an upgrade.

That being said, nothing is 100% certain, therefore [take a full system back-up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) of your PC (you're definitely user type 4) and then proceed with the upgrade.

If the upgrade would fail, just restore the system back-up and you're back where you were!

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask